# Conditional fill up of dataframe based on other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. The first dataframe `df` contains 5-minute (return) data and the hour and minute of the index

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2018-01-05', freq='5T')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(dates),1), index=dates, columns=list(['Ret']))
df['Hour'] = df.index.hour
df['Minute'] = df.index.minute
tmp = df['Ret'].groupby([df['Hour'],df['Minute']]).mean().to_frame()
```

So now `tmp` contains a MultiIndexed dataframe, it has two levels hours and minutes. What I now want to do is create a new column in `df` where I pick the correct values out of the dataframe `tmp` and put them back in the `df` dataframe.

So basically I want to create a new column in `df` by dooing a lookup of `df['Hour']` and `df['Minute']` in `tmp` and returning back the correct value, but I can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `merge`, but be careful of the syntax:

```
result = df.merge(tmp, left_on=['Hour', 'Minute'], right_index=True, how='left')
```

```
result.head()
               Ret_x  Hour  Minute     Ret_y
2018-01-01 -0.751599     0       0 -0.035756
2018-01-02 -0.650874     0       0 -0.035756
2018-01-03 -1.110701     0       0 -0.035756
2018-01-04  0.944097     0       0 -0.035756
2018-01-05  1.390296     0       0 -0.035756
```

Comment: That's amazing, works perfectly. Would you mind explaining the syntax to me? I read the documentation but I still feel like I don't grok `df.merge()`

Comment: @Rainymood Sure. left_on specifies the columns from the left dataFrame, and right_index specifies that merging for the right dataFrame is wrt the index. That's all it is.